# Trim around hexagon shape with hexSticker?

Tags: r, ggplot2, hexsticker

Suppose we have a hex sticker with an image, like so

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hexSticker)

p <- ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt), data = mtcars) + geom_point()
p <- p + theme_void() + theme_transparent()

sticker("wat.png", package="hexSticker", p_size=8, s_x=1, s_y=.75, s_width=1.3, s_height=1,filename="test.png")
system("open test.png")
```

Generates

[image]

How can we trim the hexagon so that the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p22Qx.jpg) doesn't protrude beyond the bounds of the hexagon *without* altering the image, it's size etc (that is, what is inside the hexagon *should stay exactly as-is*, we just want the content outside of the green boarder to not exist)

Comment: There is already an issue at `hexSticker` github. The solution is described here https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/hexSticker/pull/56

Comment: @atsyplenkov thanks, wasn't aware of that. Will check it out now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative using the approach of guyabel at this [issue](https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/hexSticker/issues/39#issuecomment-889786759) page of *hexSticker*:

```
library(hexSticker)
library(magick)

sticker("wotKuAu.png", package="ducker",
  h_size = 1.25, h_color = "purple4", h_fill = "#F1FF71",
  p_x = 1, p_y = 1.62, p_size = 35, p_color = "black",
  url = "stackoverflow.com/q/60426922/1199289", u_x = 1.05,
  u_y = 0.1, u_size = 6, u_angle = 30, u_color = "black",
  s_x = 1, s_y = 0.9, s_width = 1.1, dpi = 600,
  white_around_sticker = TRUE,
  filename = fname)

fuzz <- 50
p <- image_read(fname)
pp <- p %>%
  image_fill(color = "transparent", refcolor = "white", fuzz = fuzz, point = "+1+1") %>%
  image_fill(color = "transparent", refcolor = "white", fuzz = fuzz, point = paste0("+", image_info(p)$width-1, "+1")) %>%
  image_fill(color = "transparent", refcolor = "white", fuzz = fuzz, point = paste0("+1", "+", image_info(p)$height-1)) %>%
  image_fill(color = "transparent", refcolor = "white", fuzz = fuzz, point = paste0("+", image_info(p)$width-1, "+", image_info(p)$height-1))
image_write(image = pp, path = "hexDucker_trans.png")
file.show("hexDucker_trans.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE** please see [@Marcinthebox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011862/5783745)'s answer (it will create a transparent background, as opposed to a white one, which is what you'll want 99% of the time).

Old answer as follows:

---

This can be done with the option `white_around_sticker = TRUE`, e.g.

Like so

```
sticker("wat.png", package="hexSticker", p_size=8, s_x=1, s_y=.75, s_width=1.3, 
s_height=1,filename="test.png", white_around_sticker = T)
```

[image]

Comment: This unfortunately does not produce a transparent background.

Comment: @Marcinthebox I haven’t tested this in a while, but I seem to recall the same. Perhaps you could ask a new question or place a bounty on this question pointing out that the current answer doesn’t provide a transparent background (if you go with the latter, I’ll un-accept my answer, since there may be a superior one)

Comment: I actually managed something with help from the comment here: https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/hexSticker/issues/39#issuecomment-889786759. I will write another answer if you like.

Comment: @Marcinthebox nice work, please do